# difference in for each loop

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to use for each loop in c++.

this->Functions is a vector.

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Sum_Function> > Functions;
```

After reading i came across two different ways to do for each.

```
bool Container::HasFunction(std::string stdstrFunctionName )
{
    for (auto &func : this->Functions)
    {
        if (func->getFunctionName() == stdstrFunctionName)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 bool Container::HasFunction(std::string stdstrFunctionName )
 {
    for (auto it = this->Functions.begin(); it != this->Functions.end(); ++it)
    {
      auto& func = *it;
      if (func->getFunctionName() == stdstrFunctionName)
          return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

my question is that these both are nearly doing the same stuff , is there any difference between the two.

Or just different flavors for the same thing.

Comment: Another alternative: `return std::any_of(Functions.begin(), Functions.end(), [&](const auto& f) { return f->getFunctionName() == stdstrFunctionName;} );`

Comment: @Jarod i know it was demo code , i have shown the function earlier.

Comment: i will edit it.

Comment: [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly equivalent, but with some differences:

- in second snippet `func != this->Functions.end()`, `Functions.end()` is called at each loop (might be optimized by compiler with as-if rule, but requires to proof that it is the same).
- Depending of standard used (before C++17 or not), type of `Functions.end()` should be equal to the one from `Functions.end()` in the *for-range* variant. So prior to C++17, sentinel end cannot use for range and may use old for loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's mainly the same thing in two flavors. The range-based for loop expands to a loop based on iterators. But note that when the loop is critical for performance, this

```
for (auto func = this->Functions.begin(); func != this->Functions.end(); ++func)
```

is not ideal as the compiler might not be able to optimize the query for `Functions.end()` such that it is invoked only once. Recall that the termination condition in a manual `for` loop is evaluated every time, you might be better off with

```
for (auto func = this->Functions.begin(), end = this->Functions.end(); func != end; ++func)
```

As this necessarily introduces a second variable, it's definitely less readable than the range based for loop, so I'd advice you to use the range based for loop, or, as suggested in the comments, `std::any_of` from the  `<algorithm>` header.